# Matrix differenation results

Tags: matrix-calculus

Can some one tell me how to get following matrix derivative or atleast point to source where i can find?I have looked at matrix cookbook but it doesn't have anything relevant

$\frac{d}{dW}\log (\det(\sigma^2+WW^T)) $

$\frac{d}{dW}Tr ((\sigma^2 I+WW^T)^{-1}S) $ where S doesn't contain any $W$ term.

I have read some reference saying results for this can be  obtained from **Krzanowski and Marriott 1994,** but i couldn't find online reference for this too..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the matrices
$$\eqalign{
X &= (\sigma^2I+WW^T) \,\,= X^T \cr
Y &= X^{-1}S \cr
}$$
Then the two functions are
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= \log(\det(X)) \cr
\psi &= {\rm Tr}(Y) \cr
}$$
Formulas for these can be found in the cookbook. Use that information to write their differential in terms of $(dX, dY)$ then perform a change of variables to $dW.$

---

$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial X} &= X^{-T} \cr
d\phi
 &= X^{-T}:dX \cr
 &= X^{-T}:(W\,dW^T+dW\,W^T) \cr
 &= (X^{-1}+X^{-T}):dW\,W^T \cr
 &= (X^{-1}+X^{-T})W:dW \cr
 &= 2X^{-1}W:dW \cr
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial W} &= 2X^{-1}W \cr
\cr
\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial Y} &= I \cr
d\psi
 &= I:dY \cr
 &= I:dX^{-1}S \cr
 &= S^T:dX^{-1} \cr
 &= -S^T:X^{-1}\,dX\,X^{-1} \cr
 &= -X^{-T}S^TX^{-T}:dX \cr
 &= -X^{-T}S^TX^{-T}:(W\,dW^T+dW\,W^T) \cr
 &= -(X^{-1}SX^{-1}+X^{-T}S^TX^{-T}):dW\,W^T \cr
 &= -(X^{-1}SX^{-1}+X^{-T}S^TX^{-T}):dW\,W^T \cr
 &= -X^{-1}(S+S^T)X^{-1}W:dW \cr
\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial W} &= -X^{-1}(S+S^T)X^{-1}W \cr
}$$

---

**NB:** In these calculations, colons are used as a convenient product notation for the trace, i.e.
$$A:B = {\rm Tr}(A^TB)$$